# Excel Formula for changing dates

Tags: excel-formula

[image: example of problem]

If a DATE in A1 changes on a daily basis, I need for the DATA to change rows pertaining just to that DATE.
So if I have a column of dates from 12/1/16 to 12/31/16 and I enter 12/3/16 into cell A1 I only want data in 12/3/16 to be updated.

**When I enter a value in B12 it populates it in cell D2 or D3 or D4 and so on depending on what the date is.**

Comment: What formula or mechanism "automatically" enters the data into columns D and following? Edit your question and post that.

Comment: So each date in the "Daily Sales" column will have different values.  Sorry I don't know how to ask this question in the right way.

Comment: Why don't you enter the data into the right rows in the first place? A formula cannot do what you describe. It looks like you are in the wrong site to ask such a question. Try www.superuser.com for basic Excel usage questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the mechanism that "automatically enters the numbers" and add a condition that compares the date in A1 with the date in the current row.

More details about that can be provided if you update your question as suggested in the comments.